# Digital Ocean Start Express NodeJs Server on Browser Referesh

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean

I installed nodejs express framework following [Digital Ocean Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04)

With putty, i navigate to /var/www/myfolder and run npm start

When i refresh my ip address in browser, i am getting Welcome to express

If i close my putty, i am getting 502 Bad Gateway from nginx server.

So installed pm2 and here is the list

[image]

Still my browser give 502 bad gateway.

If i manually run npm start, it works.

Comment: Running this code worked... pm2 start bin/www

Comment: Yep look at your doc and find the part about `pm2 startup systemd`. It's because you are running the job under your current session... You've to run it on boot...